# Adjust spacing between subplots of panel figure (ggplot) in case of different axis.title/text properties

Tags: r, ggplot2, spacing, cowplot

I would like to adjust the spacing between plots that are aligned in a panel using the `cowplot` package when some plots contain axis titles/labels, and others don't.

**Example**

Let's create three plots:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n = 100), 
                 y = rnorm(n = 100))

plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()

plot_grid(plot, plot, plot, nrow = 1, align = "vh")
```

[image]

These plots are aligned perfectly! But often, I have a scenario in which I would like to create a 'cleaner' panel figure. One way to do this is to remove the titles/text of the y-axis of the second and third plots.

Like this:

```
plot2 <- plot + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),  
                      axis.text.y = element_blank())

plot_grid(plot, plot2, plot2, nrow = 1, align = "vh")
```

[image]

Again, perfectly aligned, but the spacing between the first and the second plot (and the second and third plot) is quite large. I would like to reduce the spacing to create a more compact plot, while the axis remain exactly the same size.

**Expected output**

[image]

Is this possible with `cowplot`? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using the [`patchwork`](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) package

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n = 100), 
                 y = rnorm(n = 100))

plot1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()

plot2 <- plot1 + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),  
                      axis.text.y = element_blank())

# install.packages("patchwork", dependencies = TRUE)
library(patchwork)

plot1 + plot2 + plot2 +
  plot_layout(ncol = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Referencing [this post on github](https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/issues/31), `plot_grid()` doesn't add any space by default and uses the margins of your plot.  To remove the space outside your plot area, you can use `them(plot.margin=...)` to remove.

With that being said... that's not what's going on here!  Printing either `plot` or `plot2` will yield a plot with no margins.  It appears the issue is with the use of the `align=` argument in `plot_grid()`.  I'm not sure why, but setting it to anything other than the default values (`align="none"`) results in the extra whitespace around the plots.  Very strange... needless to say, removing that argument fixes your problem:

#### Original code using align="vh"

```
plot_grid(plot, plot2, plot2, nrow = 1, align="vh")
```

[image]

#### Using align="none"

```
plot_grid(plot, plot2, plot2, nrow = 1, align="none")
```

[image]

Any further space would be added according to your graphics device, since the actual plot you get depends on the size and resolution of that device.

Comment: Thanks! Intriguing behavior... The answer is indeed a step towards what I'm looking for, however, when omitting the alignment argument, the axis do not stay the same size. I'm wondering if there is a way to omit the argument, while keeping the axis the same size... (Now, it seems that plots 2 and 3 have an x-axis that is the size of the x-axis of plot 1 + axis.title.y + axis.text.y)

Comment: I see what you mean.  Well, there's the `rel_widths` argument.  You can set the relative width of the first plot larger than the others, but the actual amount will be decided by trial and error.